# Saving login errors to text file using error_get_last

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, error-log

I've created a relatively simple website with multiple pages, some of them are locked and in order to access them you need to log in. The login is taken from mySQL databse, if user is in database he's allowed to go to the webpage if he isn't then he is redirected to page which says he failed to login and allows him to try loging again.

Now I would like to try and save all the attempts of failed logins into a text file, however I'm pretty unsuccessful with it.

```
    <?php
if ($row==1) 
    {
    session_register('authorisedaccess');
    $_SESSION['authorisedaccess']="a1j8ajhsbn1yh";
    header( 'Location: lockedpage.php' ) ;
    }
else
    $errormsg=error_get_last();
    $errormessage = implode(",", $errormsg);
    echo $errormessage;
    error_log($errormessage . "\n", 3, "errors.log");

header( 'Location: loginscreen.php' ) ;
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Here is part of the code which I've used for either sending user to locked page or sending him back to loginscreen page and trying to get error message to the text file, I also tried using `file_put_contents` however I was also unsuccesful, I would like to use one of those methods to do that and would appreciate your help.

Also if you could suggest better method I would appreciate it, although I would like to use this method this time to learn exactly how it works.

Comment: Sidenote: You're outputting before header because of `echo $errormessage;`, which won't echo anyway, but will still cause an error. Having error reporting ON, would've signaled that. Plus, `session_start();` needs to be loaded. 9 times out of 10, they say it is loaded.

Comment: if user not found in database query will return 0 result, its not an error so `error_get_last()` not going to give you any message, post your code of `login` so i can show you how to log unsuccessful attempts